# Anjuta terminal output not long enough

Tags: c++, ide, anjuta

I'm using Anjuta on Lubuntu to write a program which performs calculations on historical stock price data (2 years worth, one line per market day).  When I run the program and it's output is printed to the terminal in Anjuta, most of the lines are overwritten.  Anyone else out there use Anjuta and have a solution to this?  Is there a way outside of this lightweight IDE to see all of the terminal output?

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to your problem.

- You can redirect the output of your program to a file. In the terminal window of Anjuta, which in the project's root directory:

  src/executablename > outputfilename.txt

which you can then see with an editor or viewer.

- You can also redirect to a pager:

  src/executablename | less

(exit less with 'q')

- You can enter a terminal (external to Anjuta), go to the project directory, and do any of the above.

Just to be fair - Anjuta isn't *that* lightweight.